# ListView в полный размер

Tags: android, qml

Каким образом можно сделать так чтобы ListView в высоту был равен размеру всех элементов модели, чтобы в прямом смысле не было никакой прокрутки, а было полное отображение всех элементов как в случае с Repeater?
P.S: К такому решению пришел не найдя в Repeater необходимого мне параметра section.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Скиньте хоть немного исходного кода. Можете сделать скриншоты Android эмулятора и покажите на них, что не так (к примеру, в Paint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у ListView нужно задать высоту так `height: contentItem.height`

```
Rectangle {
    border.color: "red"
    border.width: 1
    width: childrenRect.width + 10
    height: childrenRect.height + 10

    ListView {
        x: 5
        y: 5
        width: 220
        height: contentItem.height
        model: idModel
        spacing: 10
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            width: 100
            height: 80
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.name
            }
        }
    }
}


ListModel{
    id: idModel
    ListElement {
        name: "item 1"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "item 2"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "item 3"
    }
}
```

Обводка красным для наглядности
[image: Обводка красным для наглядности]